# Replace a text with sed which has variabables

Tags: sed

i have a script file which is

```
**************************************************
case $arg in

-start)

**./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@**

if test $? -ne 0 ; then

exit 1

fi

;;

-version)

./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config -i -v $@

if test $? -ne 0 ; then

exit 1

fi

;;

-configtest)

./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config -i -c $@

if test $? -ne 0 ; then

echo 'failure: configuration test failed'

exit 1

fi

echo 'success: configuration was parsed successfully'

;;

-shell)

/bin/sh

;;

*)

echo "Usage: start [-start|-shell|-version|-configtest]"

exit 1

;;

**********************************************
```

i am looking to replace

```
"./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@"
```

with

```
"newtask -p $Project_Name ./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@"
```

i tired to use sed but it isnot allowing to accept vairable as contant data.
can youplease help me here i am out of my brain by tying all kind of things...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this line:

```
./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@
```

to look like this:

```
newtask -p $Project_Name ./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@
```

**Right?** Then:

Just use single quote(`'`) to wrap the command and pipe (`|`) as seperator:

```
sed -i.bak 's|./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@|newtask -p $Project_Name ./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@|' scriptfile
```

Comment: i tried  as you said bash-3.00$ sed -i.bak 's|./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@|newtask -p $Project_Name ./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@|' start1
sed: illegal option -- i

Comment: you can just ignore `-i.bak` part if doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's|./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@|newtask -p $Project_Name ./$PRODUCT_BIN -d $PRODUCT_SUBDIR/config $@|' scriptfile`